# How to convert PHP script to PDO properly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I have a lot of scripts that I need to convert to PDO. My scripts are in mysqli_ and I keep reading online different ways of doing the same thing. Can someone please explain the differences?

Again, sorry if I'm asking for simple stuff but the documents online confuse me.

Thanks in advance.

**my original PHP script in mysqli_:**

```
    <?php
include 'db_conn_pdo.php';

//preparing query


$desk_query = "SELECT 
                                coordinate_id, 
                                x_coord, 
                                y_coord, 
                                section_name, 
                                station_number, 
                                ver_hor
                            FROM coordinates";


$station_query = "SELECT
                                    coordinate_id,
                                section_name,
                                station_number,
                                x_coord,
                                y_coord,
                                username,
                                hostname
                                FROM
                                sandbox_maesc4.coordinates c
                                INNER JOIN
                                softphone_materials_updater.workstations w
                                ON w.pod = c.station_number
                                INNER JOIN
                                sandbox_maesc4.workstation_userlogged wsu
                                ON w.ws = wsu.hostname
                                WHERE wsu.lastupdate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 10 MINUTEs";       
/**************************/

$desk_stmt    = $dbh->query($desk_query);

while($row  = $desk_stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){   
                $id       = $row['coordinate_id'];
                $x_pos    = $row['x_coord'];
                $y_pos    = $row['y_coord'];
                $sec_name = $row['section_name'];
                $sta_num  = $row['station_number'];
                $position = $row['ver_hor'];

                $class = 'desk_box_ver';
                if($position == 'horizontal'){
                    $class = 'desk_box_hor';
                }
                    echo '<div class="' . $class . '" data-rel="' . $id . '" style="left:' . $x_pos . 'px;top:' . $y_pos.'px;">' . $sta_num . '</div>' . "\n";
            }

$station_stmt = $dbh->query($station_query);

while($row  = $station_stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$id       = $row['coordinate_id'];
    $sec_name = $row['section_name'];
    $sta_num  = $row['station_number'];
    $x_pos    = $row['x_coord'];
    $y_pos    = $row['y_coord'];

echo '<div class="station_info_" id="station_info_' . $id . '" style="left:' . $x_pos . 'px;top:' . $y_pos . 'px;"><p class="numb">Section:' . $sec_name . '<br>Station:' . $sta_num . '<br></p></div>' . "\n";
}//end while
?>
```

**What is the difference between these two in PDO:**

```
$station_stmt = $dbh->query($station_query);
//and
$station_stmt = self::$tdb->prepare($station_query);
```

**and how can I use these two lines in mysqli_ to check if my query is good in PDO**

```
$station_result = mysqli_query($conn,$station_query);

if($station_result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}
```

**For mysqli_ while loop in PDO I used this:**

```
while($row  = $station_stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

is  there another way of doing it?

finally, is including the connection at the top of the script a good idea like in mysqli_?

Thank you

Comment: I cannot answer your questions.But I just went trough this youtube tutorial on PDO. Very good. If you are interested https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc

Comment: Counter question: Are you really mixing `mysqli_` with PDO?

Comment: @Fred-ii- no I am not, I posted my original script in pure mysqli_ and below it its what I tried using in PDO. I get some errors

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Fred-ii- im getting **Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\...pdotest2.php on line 55** which is my second WHILE LOOP

Comment: There exists a rich [documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) about all PDO classes, their methods and attributes and how they interact. There are probably also tons of tutorials, examples and forum threads everywhere.

Comment: I'd say your query failed for `$station_query` and as this is related to JOINS, I am not the right person to help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two in PDO:
>
> $station_stmt = $dbh->query($station_query); $station_stmt =
>   self::$tdb->prepare($station_query);

The first one is a straight query, it is not prepared (e.g: `SELECT * FROM station`)

The second one is being prepared.(e.g: `SELECT * FROM desk WHERE id = ?`)

Use `query()` only if the query has no parameters

Use `prepare()` when you want to bind values to a query

> and how can I use these two lines in mysqli_ to check if my query is
>   good in PDO
>
> $station_result = mysqli_query($conn,$station_query);
>   if($station_result === false) { die(mysqli_error()); }

It is the same thing, check if `query()` returns `false`:

```
$station_stmt = $dbh->query($station_query);
if (!$station_stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    die();
}
```

> For mysqli_ while loop in PDO I used this: while($row  = $station_stmt
>   -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

`PDO` offers  `fetchAll()`, you can use it to fetch all rows at once:

```
$row = $station_stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

---

`MINUTE` takes no `s`

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -  INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

try this approach:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    if(!$dbh){
        echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
        print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
        die();
    }

    get_desk_coordinates($dbh);
    get_station_coordinates($dbh);


} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


/**
 * @param $dbh
 */
function get_desk_coordinates($dbh)
{
    $desk_query = "SELECT
                    coordinate_id,
                    x_coord,
                    y_coord,
                    section_name,
                    station_number,
                    ver_hor
               FROM coordinates";

    $desk_stmt = $dbh->query($desk_query);

    while ($row = $desk_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $row['coordinate_id'];
        $x_pos = $row['x_coord'];
        $y_pos = $row['y_coord'];
        $sec_name = $row['section_name'];
        $sta_num = $row['station_number'];
        $position = $row['ver_hor'];

        $class = 'desk_box_ver';
        if ($position == 'horizontal') {
            $class = 'desk_box_hor';
        }
        echo '<div class="' . $class . '" data-rel="' . $id . '" style="left:' . $x_pos . 'px;top:' . $y_pos . 'px;">' . $sta_num . '</div>' . "\n";
    }
}



/**
 * @param $dbh
 */
function get_station_coordinates($dbh)
{
    $station_query = "  SELECT
                    coordinate_id,
                    section_name,
                    station_number,
                    x_coord,
                    y_coord,
                    username,
                    hostname
                    FROM sandbox_maesc4.coordinates c
                    INNER JOIN
                    softphone_materials_updater.workstations w
                    ON w.pod = c.station_number
                    INNER JOIN
                    sandbox_maesc4.workstation_userlogged wsu
                    ON w.ws = wsu.hostname
                    WHERE wsu.lastupdate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -  INTERVAL 10 MINUTE";

    $station_stmt = $dbh->query($station_query);

    while ($row = $station_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $row['coordinate_id'];
        $sec_name = $row['section_name'];
        $sta_num = $row['station_number'];
        $x_pos = $row['x_coord'];
        $y_pos = $row['y_coord'];

        echo '<div class="station_info_" id="station_info_' . $id . '" style="left:' . $x_pos . 'px;top:' . $y_pos . 'px;"><p class="numb">Section:' . $sec_name . '<br>Station:' . $sta_num . '<br></p></div>' . "\n";
    }
    //end while
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks a lot for your time and help for explaining this. It helped me make the difference, I'll read more about PDO. thanks again

Comment: You made the right choice, PDO is far superior and well documented, enjoy